# Silverlight object in an asp.net MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I am trying to incorporate a silverlight object in one of my controller's views and for some reason the silverlight doesn't display at all... everything works fine in the aspx and html test page.

my code in the view looks like this:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="source" value="../../ClientBin/PatientForms.xap"/>
<param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
<param name="background" value="white" />
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" />
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40624.0" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/></a>
</object>
```

in my view i get nothing at all, if i try to run it in IE64 bit i get the You need silverlight img link as listed in the object's content. I have googled and googled but to no avail... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what I did but I think the containing div wasn't auto sizing to the size of the silverlight content, when viewing in Ie7 my content was visible so I set manual height/width to the div and now I can view in firefox/ie8.

Success!~